# how to manage top, left bottom and other spacing on WinForm form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on a Win Forms application which has tab and many tab pages are there. All of these are having many contorls on them. I need to manage form's top,left, right and bottom margins. Before I was managing this manaually by selecting and moving controls/ labels and by trying to make there margin equal but it is a little hard after some tabs to manage margions of form and contorls in form and also between controls.

Please advice what can be best and professional way to manage this.

**Edit**
My conrol heraricy is as below:

**Form > Tab Contorl > Tab Page > Form Spliter > Input Controls**
Form Spliter is Dock to Left.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify wether this is WinForms or WebForms. Your title says "winform form" but your question says "web forms application".

Comment: Oh I ma sorry David, it is Win Form. corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Set each tab page's `Padding` property (it's in the Property Grid in the Properties panel). It will help with aligning controls using the visual designer. Also make sure you're using the `Anchor` property to handle resizing without needing to write your own code.

Note that if you have a form with lots of tab pages with lots of controls on, chances are you're doing something wrong.

The best approach is to create a composite UserControl for each tab page. It really does simplify things.

Comment: Thanks David, can you please advice how I should Anchor property ? I am trying passing but it is not causing any change. Also I am not making spacing by code.

Comment: When a control is Left-anchored to its parent, it means the distance between its left edge and its parent's left edge will be the same, so when a control that is both left and right-anchored it means the control will stretch horizontally to ensure the right-right and left-left distances are kept the same.

Comment: The anchor property only takes effect during resize events, it does not make any instantaneous visible changes.

Comment: Can you please see my edit. 

Is there anything I should do to make padding working ?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot please?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving controls one by one , you can use the easiest way. Click on the window then Press **ctrl+A** then press **Arrow Buttons**. This helped a lot for me.